# Running gunicrn_start.sh with --preload: Error Empty module name

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have a django project set up, with gunicorn. I have the following gunicorn_start:

```
#! /bin/bash

NAME="ostabs2"
DJANGODIR=/srv/osmium/ostabs2
SOCKFILE=/srv/osmium/run/gunicorn.sock
USER=tabuser
GROUP=webapps
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=ostabs2.settings
DANGO_WSGI_MODULE=ostabs2.wsgi

echo "Starting $NAME as 'whoami'"

cd $DJANGODIR
source /srv/osmium/venv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --preload \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --log-level=debug \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-file=ostabsgun.log
```

Running

```
gunicorn ostabs2.wsgi:application
```

on the command line works fine, but the gunicorn_start script gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/osmium/venv/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/srv/osmium/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/srv/osmium/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 185, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/srv/osmium/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/srv/osmium/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.setup(app)
  File "/srv/osmium/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 113, in setup
    self.app.wsgi()
  File "/srv/osmium/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/srv/osmium/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/srv/osmium/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/srv/osmium/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ValueError: Empty module name
```

What would cause this error? Is there an error in the project, or a missing dependency?  I have checked user permissions on all files and directories and tabuser has full read/write access. How can I track down the cause of this problem?

UPDATE: I have followed the advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384576/problems-setting-up-django-valueerror-empty-module-name) question, the database definitions are correct (I can run syyncdb both locally and on the server).  There are no empty strings in the installed apps section, and I have removed references throughout the app to libraries which are no longer used.
Is there anything else which can cause this error?

Comment: Is it because the app declaration is at the start? I always do `gunicorn [OPTIONS] wsgi`

Comment: I'm following the structure from http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Comment: So I went through the whole app, and made sure that all dependencies referred to everywhere were loaded in the requirements.txt, and made some changes to the directory structure and the scripts.  This did the trick, though I now have another problem - see next question.